# May I do IF OR THEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In the following, there are two IF checks that dispatch to the same `table_a`:

```
SET @first = substr(new.data, 1, 1);

IF @first = 0x15 THEN

    INSERT INTO table_a (    
        id,
        time,
        data
    ) VALUES (
        new.id,
        new.time,            
        new.data
    );

ELSEIF @first = 0x16 THEN 

    INSERT INTO table_a ( 
        id,
        time,
        data
    ) VALUES (
        new.id,
        new.time,            
        new.data
    );
```

Is it, instead, possible to write something like?

```
IF @first = 0x15 | 0x16 THEN
    INSERT INTO table_a (    
        id,
        time,
        data
    ) VALUES (
        new.id,
        new.time,            
        new.data
    );
```

Comment: You mean using `IN(...)`?

Comment: Not sure If I understood what you mean?

Comment: You need to [read the documentation more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) because a lot if this is covered in there.